# Cannot edit annotations in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, annotation, utility-network

I am trying to edit the symbology and make some other changes to an annotation feature class I just made. However, I cannot make any changes to the annotation feature class. Any time I click apply, or click the green checkmark, it says annotation edit failed.

I tried googling the issue and found this page- [Problem: Unable to edit annotation features in ArcGIS Pro](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000021713), which suggests using the upgrade dataset tool. However when I try to use it on the annotation feature class, I cannot run it, I get an error saying the dataset is already upgraded.

Some background on my data - I am working on an enterprise GDB which has an electric utility network dataset. The annotation feature class I have made is linked to a subtype group layer through a relationship class.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS pro and what version of Enterprise Geodatabase are you on?

Comment: Electric utility geodatabases are likely to be stuck at 10.2.2, which is beyond the ability of modern Pro releases to modify.

Comment: Be careful...you will not be able to see Pro-upgraded anno in even recent versions of ArcMap. So can you keep editing in ArcMap (it is somewhat better for anno editing)?